# Index Match 2 columns and find lowest Value

Tags: excel, indexing, match

Im struggling to get a formula to work for the following any help apreciated.

Eg. AB DD match with DD AB lowset value of the matched pair is DD AB 1.29 and result in Column 4

The Pairs are always opposing.

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 |

```
   AB        DD       2.34        0

   XC        TT       0.34        1

   ST        HU       3.57        0

   DD        AB       1.29        1

   TT        XC       1.01        0
```

Comment: Why is the result for ST|HU 0?

Comment: Hi Jos, in theory HU ST would be further down the column and have a lower result than ST HU. hope that makes sense?

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you have Office 365?

Comment: Im using office 2019

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data in `A1:C5`, in `D1`:

`=N(C1=MIN(MINIFS(C$1:C$5,A$1:A$5,CHOOSE({1,2},A1,B1),B$1:B$5,CHOOSE({1,2},B1,A1))))`

and copied down as required.

Note that this also assumes that a 'pair' exists for every entry.

Comment: Hi Jos, Many thanks for the formula, however im getting a result of 1 in every row.

Comment: Perhaps your version of Excel requires that formula to be committed with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`?

Comment: An opposing pair does exist for every entry

Comment: Thats got it! Thanks Jos very much apreciated

Comment: No worries. Cheers, Mark.